# Select elements with data-attribute date value older than current server date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of events that each have a custom data attribute containing a date:

```
<ul class="event-list">
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150218"></li>
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150522"></li>
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150928"></li> 
</ul>

<ul class="old-event-list">

</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is select all of the `li.event-item` elements within `ul.event-list` whose data-event-date attribute is older than the current (server time) date, and then move them to `ul.old-event-list`.

I know i can use `appendTo` to move the elements, but I have no idea how to select only the elements with an older date attribute than whatever the current server date is.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the elements and use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to return elements whose `data-event-date` attribute value is greater/less than a certain value.

Then you would chain the [`.appendTo()` method](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) in order to append the returned elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lcnpgbf/)

```
$('.event-list .event-item[data-event-date]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('event-date') > 20150522;
}).appendTo('.old-event-list');
```

Of course you could dynamically retrieve the current date in JS rather than hardcoding one.

Comment: This is what ended up being the most reliable solution, sorry it's late but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a date format that the `Date` object understands then you could rather easily do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var old = $(".old-event-list");
    $(".event-list .event-item").each(function () {
        var date = new Date($(this).data("event-date"));
        if (date < now) {
            $(this).appendTo(old);
        }
    });
});
```

How to parse a date formatted as `20150522` is a question all its own. It would be much easier to just use a format that Javascript understands, such as `2015-05-22`. In PHP it would be `date('Y-m-d', $time)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("[data-event-date^=2015]").map(function(i, el) {
  return Number($(el).data("event-date")) > (new Date()).toJSON()
           .replace(/[^\d]/g, "").slice(0, 8) 
         ? $(".old-event-list").append(el) : null
});
```

```js
$("[data-event-date^=2015]").map(function(i, el) {
  return Number($(el).data("event-date")) > (new Date()).toJSON().replace(/[^\d]/g, "").slice(0, 8) ? $(".old-event-list").append(el) : null
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="event-list">
  old list
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150218">old</li>
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150522">new</li>
    <li class="event-item" data-event-date="20150928">new</li> 
</ul>

<ul class="old-event-list">
new list
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following code**

```
function pad(number, length) {//small function to pad a number with leading zeros
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
    str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
    }
    $('.event-item').each(function() {
        var edate = $(this).attr('data-event-date'); // get the value from data-event-date attribute
        var fdate = new Date();
        var year = fdate.getFullYear();
        var month = fdate.getMonth();
        var day = fdate.getDate();
        var now = year;
        if(day<=9) {
           now += pad(day,2);
        }
        if(month<=9) {
           now += pad(month,2);
        }
        if(now>edate) {
           $('.old-event-list').html('<li class="event-item">'+$(this).text()+'</li>'); // put the old dates in old eventList
            $(this).remove(); // remove item from current list
        }
    });
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/8coakc37/1/